# Pycharm 5.0.4 auto completion cannot fully work

Tags: python, import, autocomplete, beautifulsoup, pycharm

I am new and using pycharm 5.0.4 for python coding. I found for some library, my Pycharm cannot automatically pop out the help hint for the potential method/class membership etc. Like below, the soup should have the get_text() method and other methods, but the IDE doesn't pop up the menu let me can choose.

I do see other people can use this in their pycharm, do I miss anything setting?

Thanks,

[Please see below graph showing that I didn't get the pop up menu when I need the hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEFTr.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work via the built into Pycharm ["Type Hinting"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/5.0/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html). Add an `type: list[Tag]` inline comment to the line where the results of `select` are assigned to a variable:

[image]

Note that you would need to import `Tag` class in this case:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
```

Comment: Thanks very much, It works! Also is there anyway to avoid the 'Tag' for individual lines but apply globally instead? I do see some people (through online video stream though), they can get the 'Type hint' even with the list element without the 'Tag' in the line?

Comment: @henry actually, not sure how did that play out. Could you point me to the place you've seen that worked? Thanks.

Comment: I uploaded the video clip to "  https://youtu.be/VTO4zIwECi0  ", please pay attention to the position of 40'' where I pause a while to see how the pop out 'type hinting. You can use HD to play the video. Thanks,

Comment: @henry thanks for that! Could you point what PyCharm and beautifulsoup versions were used in this case? I've tried with 2016.1 and 4.4.1 respectively - no luck without the explicit type hint.

Comment: From the stream video, it is using the bs4 for beautifulsoup. And for the pycharm, I think it is 2016.1 community edition.